# Prove that for $x_1 \in [a, b], x_2 \in [\min\{f(a), f(b)\}, \max\{h(a), h(b)\}]$ that $x_2 \leq f(x_1)$ and $x_2 \geq h(x_1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, solution-verification

Suppose $a \leq x_1 \leq b$ and $c \leq x_2 \leq d$ where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$ and

$$c = \min\{f(a), f(b)\}$$
$$d = \max\{h(a),  h(b)\},$$

where $f()$ and $h()$ are linear functions. I want to show that this implies
$$x_2 \geq f(x_1)$$ and
$$x_2 \leq h(x_1)$$

Proof: Given $x_2 \geq c$, i.e., $x_2 \geq min \{f(a), f(b)\}$, then $x_2 \geq f(x_1)$ because $x_1 \in [a, b]$ and $f(x_1)$ is a linear function in $x_1$. On the other hand, given $x_2 \leq d$, i.e., $x_2 \leq  max\{h(a), h(b)\}$, then $x_2 \leq h(x_1)$ because $x_1 \in [a, b]$ and $h(x_1)$ is a linear function in $x_1$.

Is the above proof correct, or are there more details that I'm missing?

Comment: $x_2\ge\min\{f(a),f(b)\}$ should not imply $x_2\ge f(x_1)$ as $\min\{f(a),f(b)\}$ gives the minimum of $f$ in $[a,b]$. Perhaps you are confusing with $x_2\ge\max\{f(a),f(b)\}$?

Comment: I think you have written the reverse: it should be $c=\max\{f(a),f(b)\},d=\min\{h(a),h(b)\}$. In which case this question is mainly about observing that a linear function obtains its extreme values on the end-points of the domain interval.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thanks. So the argument would hold if $c = max\{f(a), f(b)\}, d = min\{h(a), h(b)\}$?

Comment: Yeah, then it is pretty straightforward no? One of $f(a),f(b)$ has to be the maximum of $f(x)$ over $[a,b]$, which is thus given by $c=\max\{f(a),f(b)\}$. So we have $x_2\ge c\ge f(x_1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not at all true in general. Take $[a,b]=[0,1],f(x)=x,h(x)=2-x$.

Then $c=\min\{0,1\}=0,d=\max\{2-0,2-1\}=2$.

Take $x_2=c=0,x_1=1/2$. Then $x_2=0\not\ge f(x_1)=1/2$.

Take $x_2=3/2,x_1=1$. Then $x_2=3/2\not\le f(x_1)=1$.